# What did the Oracle take from the Merovingian?

Tags: the-matrix

In *The Matrix Revolutions*, we hear the Merovingian say that the Oracle must have found a new shell, but then goes on to say:

> I do hope, however, she has the good manners to learn her lesson, and to remember that there is no action without consequence, ***and if you take something from me, you will pay the price.***

So, what did the Oracle take from him that made her incur this consequence? What was the action *"taken"* that caused his *"reaction"*?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

She helped the Zionese Rebels take [The Keymaker](https://matrix.fandom.com/wiki/The_Keymaker) from him.

> **The Oracle:** *Then Zion will fall. Our time is up. Listen to me, Neo. You can save Zion if you reach The Source, but to do that you will need the Keymaker.*
>
> **Neo:** *The Keymaker?*
>
> **The Oracle:** *Yes, he disappeared some time ago. We did not know what happened to him until now. He’s being held prisoner by a very dangerous program, one of the oldest of us. He is called the Merovingian, and he will not let him go willingly.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Matrix Reloaded: Transcript](https://www.matrixfans.net/movies/the-matrix-reloaded/transcript/)</sup></sub>